# QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK only working partially (with QuickBooks Online)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

The QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK is giving me a hard time.

I'm trying to use it to sync invoice data. I can successfully get authorization using OAuth 2.0 and connect my client PHP web application to QuickBooks Online. However, while I can successfully make a getCompanyInfo call and receive the results, I can't make a getUserInfo call (or most of the other API calls for that matter), as it will complain about the "access token object" not being set yet.

While connecting to QuickBooks and getting authorization, everything seems to work accurately - and the access token object is successfully placed in the PHP Session. But for some reason, it complains when I try to get the UserInfo data, or use any of the other API calls.

Here's the error that I receive:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\SdkException: [0]: Can't get OAuth 2 Access Token Object. It is not set yet.

thrown in /compiled/src/Core/OAuth/OAuth2/OAuth2LoginHelper.php on line 129
```

Here's how I try to get the UserInfo:

```
$dataService->updateOAuth2Token($accessToken);
$OAuth2LoginHelper = $dataService->getOAuth2LoginHelper();
$result = $OAuth2LoginHelper->getUserInfo();
```

Again, getting the CompanyInfo works without any problems.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Below I'm including the code from apiCall.php (from the HelloWorld example package, further edited by myself). This file is used to make requests through Ajax after I already connected to and received authorization from QuickBooks Online.

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\ServiceContext;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\Http\Serialization\XmlObjectSerializer;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;

session_start();

function makeAPICall()
{

    // Create SDK instance
    $config = include('config.php');
    $dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
        'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
        'ClientID' => $config['client_id'],
        'ClientSecret' =>  $config['client_secret'],
        'RedirectURI' => $config['oauth_redirect_uri'],
        'scope' => $config['oauth_scope'],
        'baseUrl' => "development"
    ));

    /*
     * Retrieve the accessToken value from session variable
     */
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['sessionAccessToken'];
    $dataService->throwExceptionOnError(true);

    /*
     * Update the OAuth2Token of the dataService object
     */
    $dataService->updateOAuth2Token($accessToken);

    //Get the requested data:
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "action", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $method = "get$action";

    switch($action){
        case "CompanyInfo":
            $result = $dataService->$method();
            break;

        case "UserInfo":
            $OAuth2LoginHelper = $dataService->getOAuth2LoginHelper();
            $result = $OAuth2LoginHelper->getUserInfo();
            break;

        case "InvoiceExample":
            $allInvoices = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Invoice");
            $result = $allInvoices;
            break;
    }


    var_dump($result);

    return $result;
}

$result = makeAPICall();

?>
```

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Intuit (QuickBooks) support team provided the answer to me. In my ApiCall code above, I had to use the following code to make the UserInfo request:

```
$result = $OAuth2LoginHelper->getUserInfo($accessToken->getAccessToken(), 'development');
```

Obviously, if this would involve production keys, I would have to replace 'development' with 'production'.